# how to set height for fancybox2 dynamically based on content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

How increase dynamically height of the fancybox2 when content is big. Right now I set it like below

```
 $('.fancybox-wrap').width(810);
 $('.fancybox-wrap').height(450);
 $('.fancybox-inner').width(800);
 $('.fancybox-inner').height(450);
 $.fancybox.reposition();
```

Above is working if content is small. If content is big I am getting vertical scroll bar. Width is fine for me. Only concern on height change dynamically.

```
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" id="box_front_bottom" style="display: none;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
           <div class="panel-heading text-center">
               <h2> <span class="text-center red">SPE Customer Services</span></h2>
               <span class="text-left">Thank you for contacting us!</span>
           </div>
           <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            @Html.Label("First Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7" id="formFirstName">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                     ---
                     ----
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        @Html.Label("Description", new { @class = "control-label" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7" id="formDescription">
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, in your example, you are not changing the height.

Comment: $('.fancybox-wrap').width(810);
 $('.fancybox-wrap').height(450);
 $('.fancybox-inner').width(800);
 $('.fancybox-inner').height(450); is doing? now I need dynamically.